# TypeScript: Generic type for interface with one required field

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function `f` that takes a string, and creates an object, where `key` is the only field set.

I also want the function to typecheck the interface `A` to make sure that the `key`-field is the only *required* field on the object. (There will be other optional fields).

**Problem:**

Is it possible to express the type `A` so that function `f` is valid – and doesn't produce a type error – and still typechecks `A` correctly when used?

```js
export function f<A extends { key: string }>(key: string): A {
  return { key }; // This produces compile error TS2322: (see below)
}

// This be a few different interfaces, but they all have in common that
// the key-field is the only required field.
interface WithKey {
  key: string;
  ignoreMe?: string;
}

const result = f<WithKey>('myKey');
```

**Compiler error:**

> TS2322: Type '{ key: string; }' is not assignable to type 'A'.   '{ key: string; }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'A', but 'A' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{ key: string; }'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your statement says that it accepts a type that has to have `key` of `string` and this type will be returned.

it means if I pass there

```js
{key: 1, requiredField: 5}
```

it returns the same type where I have `requiredField`.

But the implementation `return { key }` breaks this statement, because it doesn't return `requiredField` anymore. This causes TS2322.

A possible solution - simply say interface you return.

```js
export function f(key: string): { key: string } { // <- return type
  return { key };
}

interface WithKey {
  key: string;
  ignoreMe?: string;
}

const result: WithKey = f('myKey');

result.key; // works
result.ignoreMe // works (undefined)
```

Comment: Excellent answer that put me on the right path. I was overthinking it a bit too much. :) Thanks @satanTime!

Comment: Here is the code that I ended up with in my project: https://github.com/ItemConsulting/enonic-fp/blob/79301458ed8dcb5418c617f7516ba2639ff38dc4/src/utils.ts#L75-L79